# Qt mismatch of coordinates

Tags: qt

I added a itemgroup (inherited from QObject and QGraphicsItemGroup) to the coordinates (25,0),  then I added an ellipse to the coordinates (25, 0) and added a picture. (CanvasScene  inherited from QGraphicsScene). I also drew the position of the group.
[image]

Why the coordinates of itemgroup and  ellipse don't match? And why x-position of image equal to x-positon of itemgroup?

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QMouseEvent>
//-----------------------------------------
class MoveItem : public QObject, public QGraphicsRectItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(QGraphicsItem)
public:
    MoveItem(const QString& path, uint64_t& zc, QGraphicsRectItem *parent = nullptr);
    ~MoveItem();
    QRectF boundingRect() const override;
signals:
protected:
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) override;

private:
    QImage qimage_;
    QPixmap pixmap_;
    QRectF rect_;
    uint64_t& zCounter_;
};


//-----------------------------------------
class ItemGroup : public QObject, public QGraphicsItemGroup
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(QGraphicsItem)
public:
    ItemGroup(uint64_t& zc, QGraphicsItemGroup *parent = nullptr);
    ~ItemGroup() = default;

protected:
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) override;
private:
    uint64_t& zCounter_;
};



//-----------------------------------------
class CanvasScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
public:
    CanvasScene(uint64_t& zc, QGraphicsScene *scene = 0);
    ~CanvasScene() = default;

private:
    uint64_t& zCounter_;
    ItemGroup* itemGroup_ = nullptr;
};


//-----------------------------------------
#define ZOOM_FACTOR 1.15
class CanvasView : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CanvasView(QWidget* parent = 0);
    ~CanvasView();

    void addImage(const QString& path, QPointF point);
    void setZoomFactor(double factor) { zoomFactor_ = factor; }
protected:
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event) override;
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event) override;
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event) override;
    void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* event) override;
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) override;
    virtual QString setToolTipText(QPoint imageCoordinates);
    void drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect) override;
private:
    CanvasScene* scene_;
    double zoomFactor_;
    bool pan_;
    bool panStartX_;
    bool panStartY_;
    uint64_t zCounter_ = 0;
};



QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    CanvasView* canvasWidget;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"

MoveItem::MoveItem(const QString& path, uint64_t& zc, QGraphicsRectItem *parent) :
    QGraphicsRectItem(parent), zCounter_(zc)
{
    qimage_ = QImage(path);
    rect_ = qimage_.rect();
    setAcceptHoverEvents(true);
    setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);
}

MoveItem::~MoveItem() {}

QRectF MoveItem::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF (0, 0, rect_.width(), rect_.height());
}

void MoveItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    painter->setPen(QPen(QColor(0, 160, 230),2));
    painter->drawImage(boundingRect(), qimage_);
}

//-----------------------------------------------
ItemGroup::ItemGroup(uint64_t& zc, QGraphicsItemGroup *parent) :
    QGraphicsItemGroup(parent),
    zCounter_(zc)
{
    setAcceptHoverEvents(true);
    setFlags(ItemIsSelectable|ItemSendsGeometryChanges);
}


void ItemGroup::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    painter->save();
    painter->setPen( QPen(Qt::green, 3) );
    painter->drawEllipse(this->pos(), 6,6);
    painter->setPen( QPen(Qt::darkMagenta, 3) );
    painter->drawEllipse(this->scenePos(), 3,3);
    painter->restore();
}

//-----------------------------------------------
CanvasScene::CanvasScene(uint64_t& zc, QGraphicsScene *scene) : zCounter_(zc)
{
    (void)scene;
    itemGroup_ = new ItemGroup(zc);
    itemGroup_->setHandlesChildEvents(true);

    QPointF p = {25,0};
    itemGroup_->setPos(p);
    addItem(itemGroup_);

    addEllipse(QRectF(25, 0, 3, 3), QPen(Qt::black), QBrush(Qt::green));

    ++zCounter_;
    MoveItem* item = new MoveItem("bender.png", zCounter_);
    item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, true);
    item->setPos({50,50});
    addItem(item);
}

CanvasView::CanvasView(QWidget* parent) :
    QGraphicsView(parent)
{
    zoomFactor_ = ZOOM_FACTOR;
    scene_ = new CanvasScene(zCounter_);
    setMouseTracking(true);
    setScene(scene_);
    setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate);
    setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::AnchorUnderMouse);
    setDragMode(QGraphicsView::RubberBandDrag);
    setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView::AnchorViewCenter);
}


CanvasView::~CanvasView()
{
    delete scene_;
}


void CanvasView::addImage(const QString& path, QPointF point)
{
    ++zCounter_;
    MoveItem* item = new MoveItem(path, zCounter_);
    item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, true);
    item->setPos(point);
    scene_->addItem(item);
}


void CanvasView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (pan_) {
        panStartX_ = event->position().x();
        panStartY_ = event->position().y();
        event->accept();
    }
    QGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}


void CanvasView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
         pan_ = true;
         panStartX_ = event->position().x();
         panStartY_ = event->position().y();
         event->accept();

     }
    QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(event);
}


void CanvasView::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QGraphicsView::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
        pan_ = false;
        event->accept();
      }
}

void CanvasView::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event)
{
    // When zooming, the view stay centered over the mouse
    this->setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::AnchorUnderMouse);

    auto numPixels = event->angleDelta();
//    qInfo()<<"CanvasView::wheelEvent: "<<numPixels.x()<<' '<<numPixels.y();
    double factor = zoomFactor_;//(event->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier) ? zoomCtrlFactor : zoomFactor;
    if (numPixels.y() > 0) {
        scale(factor, factor);
    } else {
        scale(1/factor, 1/factor);
    }

    // The event is processed
    event->accept();
}


void CanvasView::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    // First call, the scene is created
    if(event->oldSize().width() == -1 || event->oldSize().height() == -1) return;

    // Get the previous rectangle of the scene in the viewport
    QPointF P1=mapToScene(QPoint(0,0));
    QPointF P2=mapToScene(QPoint(event->oldSize().width(),event->oldSize().height()));

    // Stretch the rectangle around the scene
    if (P1.x()<0) P1.setX(0);
    if (P1.y()<0) P1.setY(0);
    if (P2.x()>scene_->width()) P2.setX(scene_->width());
    if (P2.y()>scene_->height()) P2.setY(scene_->height());
}


QString CanvasView::setToolTipText(QPoint imageCoordinates)
{
    (void)imageCoordinates;
    return QString("");

}

void CanvasView::drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect)
{
    setCacheMode(CacheNone);
    painter->save();
    setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor(77, 77, 77)));
    painter->fillRect(rect, backgroundBrush());
    scene_->setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor(158, 158, 158)));
    painter->fillRect(scene_->sceneRect(), scene_->backgroundBrush());
    painter->setPen( QPen(QColor(247, 0, 255),2) );
    painter->drawRect(scene_->sceneRect());
    painter->restore();
}

//-----------------------------------------------
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    canvasWidget = new CanvasView();
    canvasWidget->addImage("bender.png", {-1000, -1000});
    canvasWidget->addImage("bender.png", {1300,1300});
    setCentralWidget(canvasWidget);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    delete canvasWidget;
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc can I post a link to github project?

Comment: No, the question must be self-contained